Developing Pong's Computer Paddle "AI"
This is my logic to make the computer's paddle move:
const COMP_VELOCITY = 0.025;
const BALL_VELOCITY = 0.025;

    resetComputerPaddle() {
        this.position = 50;
        this.velocity = COMP_VELOCITY;
    }

    updateComputerPaddle(delta, ballPos) {
        this.velocity = randomNumberBetween(0.01, 0.1);
        this.position += this.velocity * delta * (ballPos - this.position);
    }


Here,
randomNumberBetween() = a random number generator viz. your standard Math.random() * range + min
delta = the time the computer takes to refresh between two frames.
ball's velocity actually increases gradually during the gameplay (by a factor of 0.000001)
My logic was that if I hard-coded the computer's velocity, it wouldn't be able to keep up once the ball sped up a lot, so it would always lose once ball was faster.
That's why I thought I could generate a velocity that's initially equal to the ball's initial velocity, but then randomizes between a certain range, so that there's a chance it'll miss.
However, in my limited trials, I haven't seen the computer lose. Is that a coincidence or is the computer still unbeatable?

Since you use the ball velocity to calculate the paddle position, it doesn't matter if you add random numbers to the velocity... If you want the AI to be able to lose, you should add some random behaviour to the position, for example a delay.
